# Placeholder for div background image in Angular 4

Tags: html, css, angular

`item.imgSrc` has a URL which takes time to load on screen. Is there any way to add a placeholder image or default image until the `item.imgSrc` image is fully loaded?

```
<div class="style" *ngFor="let item of array;    
    <div  [style.backgroundImage]="url('+ item.imgSrc +')" class="image"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[ngStyle]="{'background-image':'url(' +imageUrl+ ')'}"`

Answer (score 0):

One way, You can create a directive to set a placeholder image for an element in html.

in your case, you can do as below also :

```
<div>
    <img src="img/placeholderDefault.jpg" ng-src="{{item.imgSrc}} "  height="150px " width="300px ">
</div>
```

where when your real image is loaded then it will replace the placeholderDefault image. and you can set the ng-src image base on your need in your desired scope.

If ng-src does not work in angular 2+ then, try

```
<img src="{{item.imgSrc}}">
```

or

```
<img [src]="item.imgSrc">
```

in this case, declare an object in your scope in the controller as
`$scope.item={}` and set `$scope.item.imgSrc="defaultImagePath"` and when your new
original image loads then replace with the original image path.

Hope this idea can help you

Comment: then set <img src={{defaultimagepath}}/> and after that from angular controller and set a new value to $scope.defaultimagepath as you want. So, when the page loads, default image will be loaded  and after that when new original image is found then it will replace with the new value.